# Array to key/value JSON conversion

Tags: javascript, beginner

I'm very new to Javascript...

Below is my code to convert Array to key/value JSON. Would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this or if I use any know bad practices.

An input: `[10, [20.1, 20.2], 1]`

The output:
`{"channel_id":10, "payload":[20.1,20.2], "sequence":1}`

My working code to generate the output:

```js
let myArray = [10, [20.1, 20.2], 1]

class MyObject {
  constructor(a, b, c) {
    this.channel_id = a,
      this.payload = b,
      this.sequence = c;
  }
}

myObject = new MyObject(myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2])

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

Comment: I've updated the post to make it clear that it complete and functions correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

- Not sure that a class definition makes a lot of sense here since you don’t really have any real behavior being defined in this class.
- Destructuring can also help you populate variables from the input array directly.
- camelCase is generally preferred in JS vs. snake_case.

For example you might simplify to something like this:

```
const conversionFn = ( [ channelId, payload, sequence ] ) => {  
  return { channelId, payload, sequence };
};
```